# How does OpenGLES know which attribute an array is referring to

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm looking at an example from apple how to use vertex arrays:

```
typedef struct _vertexStruct
{
    GLfloat position[2];
    GLubyte color[4];
} vertexStruct;
enum {
   ATTRIB_POSITION,
   ATTRIB_COLOR,
   NUM_ATTRIBUTES };

void DrawModel()
{
    const vertexStruct vertices[] = {...};
    const GLubyte indices[] = {...};

    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
        sizeof(vertexStruct), &vertices[0].position);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE,
        sizeof(vertexStruct), &vertices[0].color);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLubyte),
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
}
```

([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH107-SW6))

How does OpenGL know which one is color and which one is vertex? `ATTRIB_POSITION` and `ATTRIB_COLOR` are user defined, so opengl shouldn't know what it means. Specifically I try to use constant color and vertex/texture arrays. If I'll change `ATTRIB_COLOR` to `ATTRIB_TEXTURE` OpenGL won't notice a thing, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: the following assumes OpenGL ES 2.0.

OpenGL neither knows nor cares about what the meaning behind any particular vertex attribute is. All it wants is a number: an attribute index.

Your vertex shader defines a number of attributes that it takes as inputs, using the `attribute` keyword. It is your job to connect these GLSL attributes to OpenGL attribute indices, using `glBindAttribLocation` before linking the program. So attribute 0 is only the position if you bind the shader position attribute to attribute 0.

Comment: So I can't use this without shader?

Comment: @Dani Yes, OpenGL ES 2.0 requires the use of shaders.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro: Does it provide a default shader?